# OAuth - Does my Resource Server need the endpoints 'Authorize' and 'Token'

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I am tasked at work at added an External Login to one of our applications.  The idea is that you can log in from Application A, and use your credentials from Application B in order to log into Application A.

With Application B, I am provided with a few API methods to validate a user, register user, get password, etc.  I do not have the endpoints on this API for 'Token' or 'Authorize' (generates Oauth_token).

**Actors**

Client: Application A

Resource Server: Application B

---

**Questions:**

Can I implement an OAuth solution with only access to a few methods on Application B?

I guess I am lost and grasping for ways to solve this.  I dont know how to implement a custom OAuthService Provider for this scenario.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: oAuth2 or oAuth1?  oAuth2 is much more web-server friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this tutorial which is very easy to follow. 
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

To implement the custom OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider in Application A please have a look at step 10 in the above tutorial and try something like this:

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        if(!ApplicationB.Validate(username, password))
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        // add new claims relevant for your identity (ex: PortalAlias)

        context.Validated(identity);

    }
```

Then in Application A Web API controllers just wrap calls to Application B APIs

Comment: Thanks for the response! That is a great tutorial, I have actually been studying it for 2-3 days now.  In regards to that tutorial, what I am doing is I have downloaded the 'DemoApp'.  And i want to integrate a 3rd External Login Provider.  Where would I start this? My biggest question in this scenrio is where do I start? Where do I put the URI end points (Applicaiton B doesnt use end-points, so I am not sure what to do?

Comment: Assume your ApplicationB is a library which is exposing some API.  For Application A , you build now a Client (Web / Desktop App) interface and a Web Service (assume WebApi like in the tutorial). Now in the Web Api controllers all you need to do is to wrap calls (better encapsulate this into services to avoid keeping logic into controllers) to ApplicationB APIs to get the data you need from Application B.

Comment: you are incredibly helpful.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:  Yes, you can use a single controller action.**

If you're using .net mvc, then you can implement the whole thing with one action and different Id values.  Just create an authorizationController with an action that listens for "Id" or "Token" in the format:

```
https://yoursite.com/authorization/id?[params]
https://yoursite.com/authorization/token?[params]
```

In your route, *authorization* will resolve to an action and *id/token* will both resolve to an id.

**Parameters (query or form-post)**

Then, accept the parameters you need as (optional) parameters in your method and process accordingly.  Most oAuth clients will look for an initial url, and a url to convert their autorization code into an access token.  The responses are well-known (eg - the data I expect to see from your oAuth response is well known), and the names that are posted and returned (eg - type, client_id, client_secret, token, code, redirect_uri, etc) are also well known.

**Example Service(s)**

It's helpful to work backward from a well-documented oAuth service like [the one for basecamp](https://github.com/basecamp/api/blob/master/sections/authentication.md).  At the end of the day, that's what you are trying to produce.  You could also zapier's oAuth2 docs if you need a second source to compare with.

[This article](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified) gives a great (basic) overview of how the whole process works.  The client-side calls, what the server returns, etc.  It's a good jumping-off point.

Implement as may "grant_types" as you need to, just document the ones your server supports for your consumers (or, in your case, for the developers of AppB).

**Final note:  You should make sure oAuth is the right answer.**

I feel like I need to add a quick edit and explain that oAuth might not be the right solution for the specific business problem you oulined!  Most people use oAuth2 to gain access to another app's api (not to authenticate users with another app).

The oAuth.net website says it best:

> The OAuth 2.0 specification defines a delegation protocol [...]. OAuth
>   is used in a wide variety of applications, including providing
>   mechanisms for user authentication. This has led many developers and
>   API providers to **incorrectly** conclude that OAuth is itself an
>   authentication protocol and to mistakenly use it as such.

If you are just going to try to validate users, then maybe oAuth2 is the wrong solution.

Answer (score 1):

Resource servers do not issue tokens.  Authorization servers issue tokens.

You will need an authorization server that issues tokens via an token end point and some mechanism for validating tokens.  If you can modify application B to have the token endpoint, then it can act as your authorization server.  If you cannot, you can build another application with a token endpoint to be the authorization server.  This new application would call "validate user" on application B to validate user credentials and issue tokens if they are valid.

Assuming Application A is a trusted by Application B (example: your company owns and maintains both applications), you can likely get away with only having a token endpoint by using the [resource owner flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) of OAuth.